# CSV - display rows in which specified column is empty

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have an csv file that goes like this:

```
department_id,department_name,manager_id,location_id
 10,Administration,200,1700
 20,Marketing,201,1800
 30,Purchasing,114,1700
 40,Human Resources,NaN,2400
 50,Shipping,NaN,1500
......
```

the task is to print rows in which column `manager_id` is empty, and `no headers` are displayed.

The closest approach i achieved is :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv', header=None, index_col = 0 )
null_data = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
print(null_data)
```

but it prints weird

```
Your code output:
1    2     3
0                                   
120              Treasury  NaN  1700
....
```

at the beggining.
I would be grateful with any help, not really with pandas, all approaches  would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "and no headers are displayed"?

Answer (score 0):

To get the rows where manager_id is empty, we can do `df[df['manager_id'].isnull()]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your way of reading the CSV file with `header=None` assume no column labels.  Hence, your printout shows only columns in numbers.

You can change the code reading the CSV to:

```
df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv')
```

Then, to select rows where `manager_id` is empty, you can use:

```
null_data = df.loc[df['manager_id'].isna()]
print(null_data)
```

**Result:**

```
   department_id  department_name  manager_id  location_id
3             40  Human Resources         NaN         2400
4             50         Shipping         NaN         1500
```

Comment: but what if i want it to be printed without headers ( department_id  department_name  manager_id  location_id) ?

Comment: @learningbtw  Without header then it is not a dataframe.  Or you want to show the headers as `0`, `1`, etc.  ?   If you just want the values, you can try:  `print(null_data.values)`  That is, adding `.values` at the end of `null_data` before printing

Comment: @learningbtw  Do you have any idea what display format the output should be ?  If yes, please edit your question to show it.  If no, then probably `.values` showing only the values fulfill your requirement.  Let me know how you think.

Comment: @learningbtw Let me know how you would like to display the output, whether display headers as `0`, `1`, etc. or any other else ?